# How does Spark serialization work for case classes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've run into something odd in Spark 2.2 and how it deserializes case classes. For these examples, assume this case class:

```
case class X(a:Int, b:Int) {
  println("in the constructor!!!")
}
```

If I have the following map operation, I see both my constructor and the value of 'a' messages in the executor logs.

```
ds.map(x => {
  val x = X(1, 2)
  println(s"a=${x.a})
}
```

With the following map operation, I do not see my constructor message but I do see the value of 'a' message in the executor logs. The constructor message is in the driver logs.

```
val x = X(1, 2)
ds.map(x => println(s"a=${x.a}"))
```

And I get the same behavior if I use a broadcast variable.

```
val xBcast = sc.broadcast(X(1, 2))
ds.map(x => println(s"a=${xBcast.value.a}"))
```

Any idea what's going on? Is Spark serializing each field as needed? I would have expected the whole object to be shipped over and deserialized. With that deserialization I'd expect a constructor call.

When I looked at the encoder code for Products it looks like it gets the necessary fields from the constructor. I guess I was assuming it would use those encoders for this kind of stuff.

I even decompiled my case class's class file and the constructor generated seems reasonable.

Comment: why are you defining an object in the driver as `val x` but then also referencing elements inside ds as `x`?  I'm surprised that works at all, unless the elements in your ds also have a field 'a'.  I'd work that to `ds.map(_ => println(s"a=..."))` or  more clearly `ds.foreach(_ => println(s"a=.."))` since your output type is Unit anyway.  Lastly...  try messing around with `val x` vs `def x` vs `lazy val x`.  I'd bet constructor for 'val' is in the driver, for 'def' is in executors, and not sure where lazy val ends up...  probably driver also, but it's an interesting exercise.

Comment: The return type being Unit is more laziness in my examples. Assume I'm outputting actual values. I focused on showing how I use the object.

It finds x because you can reference outer scope variables in an inner scope in scala. Plus spark knows how to interpret that. If you read up on broadcast variables what I have is what you're supposed to do. The only difference between using broadcast and not is Spark can be much smarter about not re-serializing with broadcast.

Comment: Could you provide some details? How do you test this code? In what mode? What is the type of of `ds` and how is it created?

Comment: Ds is a DataSet. It's created with the "session.read.parquet(file).as[CaseClass]" pattern. I test it on the cluster in yarn/cluster mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is using Java serialization (available because case classes extend `Serializable`) by default, which does not require the use of a constructor to deserialize.  See [this StackOverflow question for details on Java serialization/deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141440/how-are-constructors-called-during-serialization-and-deserialization).

Note that this reliance on Java serialization can cause issues, as the internal serialization format is not set in stone so JVM version differences can cause deserialization to fail.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Even with RDD API Spark doesn't necessarily use  Java serialization, and with Dataset API it shouldn't use it for data serialization at all.

Comment: Using Java Serialization seems right. The scala @transient annotation, which works with Java Serialization, correctly makes fields not be serialized.